# My Objects are teleported correctly to the location as needed but stay in the air and do not move

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Not sure if I can use stack overflow for Unity please correct me if not but:
My Objects (marbles) seem to teleport to the location correctly but stay in the air and do not respond to outside forces (as if it's kinematic still).

The teleportation works when I don't change around the objects kinematic state, but this is needed for me.
Any Ideas?

[Image of rigidbody after teleportation with the marble floating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JssB4.jpg)

When I drop my marbles outside of the map and it exits my barrier box over the world it works completely fine:

```
public Transform SpawnPoint;
public Transform SpawnPoint2;
ShootPlayerBall shootPlayerBall;
public GameObject player;
void Awake()
{
    shootPlayerBall = player.GetComponent<ShootPlayerBall>();
}
void OnTriggerExit(Collider Collider)
{
    if (Collider.gameObject.tag == "Marble")
    {
        Rigidbody Ball_physics = Collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Ball_physics.isKinematic = true;
        Collider.gameObject.transform.position = SpawnPoint.transform.position;
        Ball_physics.isKinematic = false;
        shootPlayerBall.launch = true;
    }
    else if (Collider.gameObject.tag == "TargetMarble")
    {
        Rigidbody Ball_physics = Collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Ball_physics.isKinematic = true;
        Collider.gameObject.transform.position = SpawnPoint2.transform.position;
        Ball_physics.isKinematic = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Destroy(Collider.gameObject);
    }
}
```

---

But when I try to teleport the player marbles after being on the floor for ten seconds it does not work:

```
 if (startTimer == true)
    {
        //counts down from 10 seconds using deltatime
        currentTime -= 1 * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if (currentTime <= 0.0f)
    {
        //when time is up teleports marble back to spawn
        Rigidbody Ball_physics = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Ball_physics.isKinematic = true;
        transform.position = SpawnPoint.transform.position;
        Ball_physics.isKinematic = false;
        //resets starting time
        currentTime = 10f;
        startTimer = false;
        //sets launch to true in shootplayerball script so the player can shoot again
        ShootPlayerBall refScript = GetComponent<ShootPlayerBall>();
        GetComponent<ShootPlayerBall>().launch = true;
    }
```

---

Or when I try to teleport the target marbles when in contact with the player:

```
public Transform SpawnPoint;
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision move_ball)
{
    if (move_ball.gameObject.tag == "Marble")
    {
        Rigidbody Ball_physics = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Ball_physics.isKinematic = true;
        this.transform.position = SpawnPoint.transform.position;
        Ball_physics.isKinematic = false;
    }
}
```

I have tried using Debug.Logs and found it is only teleporting once when the timer is at 0 and correctly resets. The object that they are getting teleported too is the same for leaving the map and the other code. They have a collider off with isTrigger on.

Note I am new to unity so I don't know everything.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing it in your first snippet, you're using `OnTriggerExit(Collider Collider)` and then using that collider's GameObject:

```
Rigidbody Ball_physics = Collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
```

But the thing to be aware of here is that [`OnTriggerExit(Collider)` is giving you the OTHER collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerExit.html). When you say `Collider.gameObject` you're getting the collider of the thing that is NOT `this.gameObject`.

But, in your snippets that don't work, you're using `this.gameObject`:

```
Rigidbody Ball_physics = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
```

and

```
Rigidbody Ball_physics = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
```

In your last snippet there you're checking a GameObject to see if it's a marble, but then you're not actually using THAT GameObject, you're using `this.gameObject`:

```
if (move_ball.gameObject.tag == "Marble")
{
    Rigidbody Ball_physics = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
```

I think what you mean to do instead is:

```
if (move_ball.gameObject.tag == "Marble")
{
    Rigidbody Ball_physics = move_ball.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
```

Comment: hey, I changed my last snippet to what u mentioned and it worked! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @aemeny - Glad it's working! Please upvote/accept if you're good now so this question gets closed out correctly :)

Comment: Any idea about what I could do with the 10 second count down to fix this as it doesn't rely on a collision

Comment: @aemeny - there's not enough of a snippet there for me to be able to see what's going on, but similar deal - you need to get a reference to the actual marble that's idle for 10 seconds. Basically what I think you've got is something like a player script or marble controller script, and you're setting isKinematic true and false for that script instead of for your target marbles. If you've got some trigger condition that's starting your ten second timer then you need to cache the reference to that triggering marble and, after the timer expires, teleport that marble.

Comment: Also would happily upvote your response buy sadly this is a new account and I do not have enough reputation! But thanks.

Comment: No worries :) Questions with no upvoted or accepted answer will get continuously bumped every month or so, so maybe it'll get upvoted down the road :P

Comment: Yea ofc will do later on thanks! My 10 second timer is related to the players ball they control when they land on the floor, so would I not need to just access the rigidbody as I am currently? Sorry for all the questions new to unity

Comment: @aemeny - if the script is attached to the marble you're trying to teleport, then using `this.gameObject` would be correct, but if the script is NOT attached to the marble you're trying to teleport then you need to acquire a reference to that target marble somehow. Using the `this.gameObject` keyword always refers to the GameObject to which the script is attached.

Comment: Yes, the script is connected to the marble im trying to teleport and im using 'this.gameObject' now to change the iskinematic (snippet two), that is the main problem im getting where the ball is just kinda stuck in the air or am I wrong somewhere.

Comment: @aemeny ohhh I think maybe your rigid body is asleep. If nothing contacts it for a while it goes to sleep, then it's asleep and you moved it. When you clear isKinematic it's still asleep. Try `Ball_physics.WakeUp();` after clearing isKinematic.

Comment: I tried placing this after I turned the kiematic back on and still no result the players ball still is unreactive to any outside force after teleporting.

Comment: @aemeny can you screen shot the rigid body component after it gets teleported and is stuck?

Comment: I have found if I make the marble that is stuck to inactive then set active again it makes it fall again, not sure if this helps towards the problem

Comment: Wait did you try to wake the rigid body after setting kinematic to TRUE or after setting it to FALSE? It would also be sleeping if kinematic is true. Set kinematic, move it, clear kinematic (set it to false) and the last step should be to wake it.

Comment: I have added the image to the post at the top with the rigid body and the floating marble, i set it to awake after i set the kinematic to false